# xsd для проверки xml

Tags: xml, xsd

Доброго времени.

есть XML вот такого вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfLibraryUnit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LibraryUnit xsi:type="Book">
    <NameVal>книга1</NameVal>
  </LibraryUnit>
  <LibraryUnit xsi:type="Book">
    <NameVal>книга2</NameVal>
  </LibraryUnit>
  <LibraryUnit xsi:type="Newspaper">
    <NameVal>Газета1</NameVal>
    <pageCountVal>5</pageCountVal>
  </LibraryUnit>
</ArrayOfLibraryUnit>
```

нужно написать для него xsd... я в этом деле не силен, пол дня убил и родил следующий xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="ArrayOfLibraryUnit" >
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="LibraryUnit" type="Book"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="LibraryUnit" type="Newspaper"></xsd:element>
      </xsd:choice>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="Book">
    <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="NameVal" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Newspaper">
    <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="NameVal" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="pageCountVal" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

но он работает только если в xml содержатся только книги (Book). Подскажите как правильно то?

вся трудность из-за того что объекты Book и Newspaper отнаследованы от LibraryUnit.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас `Book` и `NewsPaper` неотличимы для валидатора. Поэтому только так

```xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:element name="ArrayOfLibraryUnit">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="LibraryUnit" type="LibraryUnitType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="LibraryUnitType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="NameVal" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="pageCountVal" type="xsd:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. В итоге переделал немного саму сериализация в xml.

Изначально у меня на классе родители были такие атрибуты

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Book)), XmlInclude(typeof(Newspaper))]
```

сделал сериализацию через массив

```
public class SerializeLibraryUnits
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Book)), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Newspaper))]
    public LibraryUnit[] libraryUnits;
}
```

в итоге xml стал такого вида

```
<SerializeLibraryUnits xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <libraryUnits>
    <Book>
      <NameVal>книга1</NameVal>
    </Book>
    <Book>
      <NameVal>книга2</NameVal>
    </Book>
    <Newspaper>
      <NameVal>Газета3</NameVal>
      <pageCountVal>7</pageCountVal>
    </Newspaper>
  </libraryUnits>
</SerializeLibraryUnits>
```

Учусь... ))